# Installing XSLTForms on exist-db 5.2

Tags: exist-db, xsltforms

Given that the package manager is not offered on the eXist-db 5.2 dashboard (at least not on mine) how does one install XSLTForms on an eXist-db 5.2 installation running on an AWS EC2 instance.

Comment: Received a mailing list answer stating that you have to be logged in as Admin to see the Package Manager. I am logged in as admin.

Comment: Latest release of XSLTForms allows to write and run forms without its XSLT stylesheet: HTML custom elements, named "xforms-*", can directly be used with just the Javascript library.
This should reduce XSLTForms install to just adding static files...

Comment: Great news. Could you elaborate on that with a reference to a more detailed explanation  and ideally an example?

Comment: A short example: https://github.com/AlainCouthures/declarative4all/blob/master/public/direct/hello.htm